# Flashing components when loading page

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an issue with my template that you can see below. I think that I understand the problem, but solution is eluding me.
When I put valid data to my local storage to fulfill my condition in constructor and reload the page. My subject has null value at first, but later when subscription is completed subject has a value. It leads to an issue in my template. First it show my Login button for split second, then dropdown is shown. I would like to achive that dropdown is shown right away (if jwtToken is in localStorage).

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  authUser$: Subject<User | null> = new Subject<User | null>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const jwtToken: string | null = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    if(jwtToken) {
      const id: number = this.getIdFromToken(jwtToken);
      this.getUser(id).subscribe();
    }
  }

  getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<UserResponse>(BASE_URL + `/api/user/${id}`)
      .pipe(
        map((response: UserResponse) => {
          var user: User = {
            username: response.username,
            enabled: response.enabled,
            locked: response.locked,
            created: response.created,
            authorities : response.authorities.map((a: { authority: string }) => a.authority)
          };
          this.authUser$.next(user);
          return user;
        }),
      );
  }
}
```

Here goes my template

```
        <button *ngIf="(authService.authUser$ | async) == null" type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-2" (click)="authenticate()">Login</button>
        <div *ngIf="authService.authUser$ | async" class="dropdown text-end pe-3">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="favicon.ico" alt="mdo" height="40" width="40" class="rounded-circle">
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Sign out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

I don't really know what to do with the issue, chatgpt didn't helped and I didn't fond any hint on internet

Comment: It sounds like you already know what's wrong. "My subject has null value at first, but later when subscription is completed subject has a value."

Could you share the templates component code? My guess to resolve this would be to have the `startWith` rxjs operator in your subscription and setting it to something not null, but then you might get the opposite effect where it shows the dropdown for a second the switches to the button if it is null then back to dropdown once the get response resolves and is emitted.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more I think if you set `localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)` as the initial value in the component then add the condition from the constructor in the component's `ngOnInit()` 
`if(jwtToken) {
      const id: number = this.getIdFromToken(jwtToken);
      this.authService.getUser(id)
    }`
It will achieve your desired effect.

Comment: I'd restructure the code to have those async methods nested or wait for them both to resolve. In other words, your `authUser` value would be set only once and at only one place, instead od being set at two async places.

Comment: Did you consider putting the get user code into an app initializer of angular? This way your app actually wait for it to resolve. Another idea would be to give some state to the subject and make it a behavior subject starting with something like "initializing" switching to "user  fetch success" or "error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all. Based on your tips I managed to edit the code.

```
export interface Auth {
  user: User | null,
  token: string | null,
  error: Error | null,
  status: "initialize" | "error" | "login" | "logout",
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  authSubject =
    new BehaviorSubject<Auth>({
      status: "initialize",
      token: localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY),
      error: null,
      user: null,
    });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    if(this.authSubject.value.token) {
      this.getUserByToken(this.authSubject.value.token).subscribe();
    } else {
      this.authSubject.next({ token: null, status: "logout", error: null, user: null, });
    }
  }

  getUserByToken(token: string): Observable<User> {
    let id: number = this.getIdFromToken(token);
    return this.getUserById(id);
  }

  getUserById(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<UserResponse>(BASE_URL + `/api/user/${id}`)
      .pipe(
        map((response: UserResponse) => {
          const user = {
            username: response.username,
            enabled: response.enabled,
            locked: response.locked,
            created: response.created,
            authorities: response.authorities.map((a: { authority: string }) => a.authority),
          } as User
          this.authSubject.next({ token: this.authSubject.value.token, status: "login", error: null, user, });
          return user;
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          this.authSubject.next({ token: null, status: "error", error, user: null, });
          return throwError(() => error);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Template:

```
      <div *ngIf="auth?.status !== 'initialize'" class="d-flex">
        <ng-template [ngIf]="auth?.status === 'login'" [ngIfElse]="elseBlock">
          <div class="dropdown text-end pe-3">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <img src="favicon.ico" alt="mdo" height="40" width="40" class="rounded-circle">
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Sign out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #elseBlock>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-2" (click)="authenticate()">Login</button>
        </ng-template>
        <app-theme-switcher/>
      </div>
```